# CSS selector issue

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

This is my html code:

```
<label for="tx_alterneteducationcatalog_subscriberadd[newSubscriber][gender]" 
class="error" id="tx_alterneteducationcatalog_subscriberadd[newSubscriber]
[gender]-error">This field is required.</label>
```

this is my css code:

```
#tx_alterneteducationcatalog_subscriberadd[newSubscriber][gender]-error{
    display: none !important
}
```

For some reason the float right not working. Even in the firebug  it is not showing that I put a `float:right !important`. Why?

Comment: `[]` is used to denote attributes, so this selector is invalid, as in: `[gender]-error` will never be correctly interpreted unless you use `*[id="#tx_alterneteducationcatalog_subscriberadd[newSubscriber][gender]-error"]` to specifically match the id of the selector as a string.

Comment: can you give me a full example of this ?

Comment: @Chester — That **is** a full example.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: this : *[id="tx_alterneteducationcatalog_subscriberadd[newSubscriber][gender]-error"]‌​ {float: right} is not working for me

Comment: @Chester while working on the snippet I posted it didn't work for me either, tbh. Cant put my finger on that.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsbin.com/yunaquzana/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @somethinghere: I don't know if this has to do with the formatting of the question, but there appears to be a line break in the id attribute. If that same line break appears in the original markup, then that's just one more to add to the multiple issues with the original markup.

Comment: neither this version is not working : label[id="tx_alterneteducationcatalog_subscriberadd[newSubscriber][gender]-error"]‌​ {float: right} for me

Comment: Weird I got this : label[for="tx_alterneteducationcatalog_subscriberadd[newSubscriber][gender]"]â€Œâ€‹{float: right} in my code . After a ctrl+u and click on my css. Any idea ?

Comment: @BoltClock let's all agree that this string is too long and complicated to be of much use and it's to error prone. As the pastebin shows it can work (I couldnt get it to work in the snippet, but after modifying it to just letters it worked so its probably some invisible chars). Any chance theres actually a length limit on css selector string...?

Comment: @somethinghere: No, it's most definitely either the newline in the HTML or some junk characters in either HTML or CSS (as just shown by the OP...).

Answer (score 3):

The selector

```css
#tx_alterneteducationcatalog_subscriberadd[newSubscriber][gender]-error
```

is not valid. The square brackets denote attribute selectors, so what you have is

```css
#tx_alterneteducationcatalog_subscriberadd
[newSubscriber]
[gender]
```

... followed by, quite literally, a syntax error in `-error` because an identifier is not expected there.

If you escape all the square brackets, the entire ID selector will be parsed correctly:

```css
#tx_alterneteducationcatalog_subscriberadd\[newSubscriber\]\[gender\]-error
```

... but I prefer just using an attribute selector to match the ID instead:

```css
[id="tx_alterneteducationcatalog_subscriberadd[newSubscriber][gender]-error"]
```

You could also select by the `for` attribute and the `.error` class rather than `id`, but it's not clear to me why a validation error would be marked up in a `label` element in the first place. The text, for one, says absolutely nothing about what field it is "labeling" exactly; all it says is that it's required.

---

I just noticed there's a line break in your `id` attribute. If this is how your actual markup appears exactly, then your markup is invalid. That being said you should still be able to account for it in your CSS with the escape sequence `\a` (see [section 4.3.7](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#strings) of the spec):

```css
#tx_alterneteducationcatalog_subscriberadd\[newSubscriber\]\a\[gender\]-error
```

```css
[id="tx_alterneteducationcatalog_subscriberadd[newSubscriber]\a[gender]-error"]
```

Comment: I think that using the `id` for this seems to be a bit too specific and I'm guessing the code could use some refactoring. I didn't know you could use escape characters in CSS though (although I hope I will never have too)

Comment: can you give me an example with the for attribute ?

Comment: @Chester `<label for="id-of-input">This label links to the input</label>`

Comment: @Chester: I'm sure you can figure it out with the id attribute example I've given.

Answer (score 1):

Because `[]` is used to denote attributes in CSS selectors, you cannot use them as classnames or ids unless you use the attribute selector to match the string as such:

```css
*[id="a[b]-c(d)"]{ color: yellow; }
```

```html
<div id="a[b]-c(d)">Selected</div>
```

This is not recommended and it's better to use **classes** for this and restrain them to the relevant conventions.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to make this work by using this code:

```
label[for="tx_alterneteducationcatalog_subscriberadd[newSubscriber][gender]"]‌​{
      float: right !important
}
```

and there was a FTP issue. After uploading it puts me some weird characters. After removing it. It works

Answer (score -1):

Square brackets are not valid characters for css identifiers: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters

Comment: They are. In fact, they have a special meaning in selectors, and that is the real reason why this selector is invalid. I suspect you meant to say "identifiers" rather than "selectors".